# directory traversal bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a structure as follows; each user in my system have their own control files under their names as directory. Example: suppose username is joe. The control files for the user is located in directory j/o/e. Likewise user joey has his files under directory j/o/e/y. One of the control files is named "files.txt".

I have to write a bash shell script that finds all users in my system that have a line including ".torrent" string in their "files.txt" and have to output the name of the user. I have no idea how to do that.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What approaches have you taken?  Why are your directories like that?

Comment: That looks like a rather unpractical directory structure. Is that homework? (hint: man find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep '.torrent' `find /top/level/directory/ -name files.txt`
```

Will output `j/o/e/y/files.txt`, for every user `joey` that has `.torrent` in their `files.txt` easy to get the username from that!.

Comment: Also, how do I modify this code to search under the directory it is executed?

Answer (score 0):

have bash 4? can try

```
cd /top/of/control
grep -Hm1 '\.torrent' ./**/*.txt
```

Comment: Also, how do I modify this code to search under the directory it is executed?